# How to use this symbol in Latex - ?

Tags: symbols

I would like to use the symbol '' in Latex (used for [Symmetric group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_group)).

Any ideas?

Comment: `\mathfrak{S}`, which requires `amssymb`?

Comment: @AdamLiter: I'd suggest an answer with a minimal, complete document.

Comment: @mbork I'd normally agree, but this is definitely a duplicate of the symbol look up question, which is why I just commented to check with the OP first before voting to close, but it looks like egreg has already closed it.

Comment: Also, welcome to TeX.SX, @RB!